# Video Editor with custom resolution support

Tags: windows, video, video-editing

I want to import a video and then:

1. Crop it
2. Apply watermark
3. Remove audio channels (optional cause I may use FFMPEG)
4. Export with the **exactly cropped size resolution**, not SD or HD standards.
   Software I need should have `H.264` (`H.265` is preferred) format support.

Please mention some software which can handle my demands.

- It need not be freeware.
- The more features the software has, the better.

Comment: Not all formats supports ANY cropped size. Some need to be multiples of 4x for example.

Answer (score 1):

FFMPEG can do most *if not all* of what you are asking for but to simplify things, *if you are a python user or ready to learn,* you can use [MoviePy](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy).

1. Crop the movie to exact size: Use [`crop(`*clip, x1, y1, width, height, centerx, centery*`)`](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/ref/videofx/moviepy.video.fx.all.crop.html?highlight=crop#moviepy.video.fx.all.crop)
2. Watermark - Lots of text and overlay effects, even rolling credits, etc.
3. Remove audio channels - Yep *just set audio to False on the write operation*
4. Export with the exactly cropped size resolution, not SD or HD standards - the [`write`](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/ref/VideoClip/VideoClip.html?highlight=write#moviepy.video.VideoClip.VideoClip.write_videofile) command gives you full control
5. H.264/H.265 - Yes basically use `write(`...`, codec='libx264',` ...`)`

Cost: Free, Gratis & OpenSource
The more features the software has, the better. - This has lots of features:

> MoviePy is a Python module for video editing, which can be used for
>   basic operations (like cuts, concatenations, title insertions), video
>   compositing (a.k.a. non-linear editing), video processing, or to
>   create advanced effects. It can read and write the most common video
>   formats, including GIF.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [Bolide Movie Creator](http://movie-creator.com) for my video editing tasks. I just checked for the custom resolution. With BMC you can set your own resolution, but the width should be a multiple of 16 and the height - the multiple of 2. I guess, it is some codec-related limits.
[image: setting custom resolution for the project]

1. You can crop video with "Zoom effect", select the desired rectangle and set zero for zoom-in and zoom-out time. Or you can enlarge the video with the mouse in the preview area and position it the way you want, so the unneeded part will be clipped
2. You can add text, images, or another video as the watermark
3. You can set audio volume to 0. I don't see the option to not save audio at all.
4. Click on resolution over the timeline and select "Custom..." popup menu item
5. h.264 with hardware acceleration support is available. No h.265

Free version adds the watermark to the saved video. I paid $40 for the license.